# MySQL - trouble writing a query that should be really easy

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an intermediate table which looks something like this (after I join 2 other tables) :

```
    ID       Meta_key   Meta_value
    

    22     Company   Amazon

    22     Address   Seattle


    25     Company   Google

    25     Address   Mountain View
```

And so on...

My question is what's the easiest way to write a single query to get BOTH the company name and address for a given ID?  What's the best way to structure this where clause since I would want something like select meta_value from table where meta_key = "Company" and meta_key = "Address" (that obviously wont work)...I'm sure there is a  simple way to do this but can't seem to think of it right now, I'll also need aliases to distinguish between the meta_value for company and address in the result set.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both keys in same row you could self-join the table

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Meta_value as "Company", t2.Meta_value as "Address"
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Meta_key = "Address"
WHERE t1.Meta_key = 'Company'
```

Or if you want single ID even simpler with subquery:

```
SELECT 
    22 as "ID",
    (SELECT Meta_value FROM table WHERE id = 22 AND Meta_key = "Company") as "Company",    
    (SELECT Meta_value FROM table WHERE id = 22 AND Meta_key = "Address") as "Address";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN meta_key ='Address'
       THEN Meta_value
       ELSE ''
END AS address,
CASE WHEN meta_key ='Company'
       THEN Meta_value
       ELSE ''
END AS company
FROM tbl where id=22
```